# Is there a more flexible alternative to diff/patch?

Tags: java, diff, patch

I'm trying to maintain a set of patches, which needs to be applied to several versions/branches of the code. The current diff/patch method (and git cherry-picking) is not flexible enough, mainly due to the dependency of the context. For example assume my patch adds a few constants in a java class. If in one version of the code another constant was inserted, exactly at the same place, patch will fail. In a general circumstance this is ok, since the order might be important, however in case of java code the order of the fields (at leaast in 99% of the cases) doesn't matter. In another example I wanted to insert one line right after another one. However the context contains in total 6 lines, and the patch is applied normally only if all of those matches.

I tried to manually edit the diff files, to keeping for example only one line of context, but then patch failed with the message "broken patch".

So I would like to know if there is a better (open source preferably) alternative to diff/patch which is more flexible.

Thank you in advance!
/Pal

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `git format-patch -U1 <revisions>`, it produces a patch with 1 line of context.

Comment: While that's probably a decent work around it's a bit of a shame if there aren't any language aware diff tools that could do this in a much better way.

Comment: I believe it is so just because it would work worse than any regular text diff. It sounds counter-intuitive, but I guess it's true. Meanwhile a lot of different text files could mean the same from a language compiler point of view, but for a human - the difference is meaningful. First of all, a source code is a text files, because good a code is written for humans, not for robots.

Comment: It's not hard to determine that .java files are written in Java and it's certainly possible to know whether a difference makes any actual difference as long as you know the language. I assume the reason is simply that it's hard and a lot of work to get right.

Comment: What exactly does mean the `actual difference`? From user perspective only whitespace changes are meaningless. And most tools already able to ignore whitespaces.

Comment: By actual difference I mean difference in resulting operations from code. For example `public class X { private int a = 1; private int b = 2; }` and `public class X { private int b = 2; private int a = 1; }` are the same in Java, yet the diff will say it's a change. This makes code clean ups (such as sorting) a MASSIVE inconvenience the moment you need to compare something before and after the clean up.

Comment: Yes, but `{private int a = 1; private int b = a + 1; }` cannot be changed. And there are a lot of more complex cases. And that also I'm trying to say... that from a human perspective it is significant difference, otherwise why have you made the code clean-up if it not the `actual difference`?

Comment: Have you never done refactoring and clean up? In large Classes there is absolutely an advantage in tidying things up, putting them in a more natural order (for example order by public/protected/private) etc. Clean up by it's very nature should NOT change functionality. Your example just shows why it's hard (which is what I said) not why it's not desirable (which seems to be what you're arguing). The fact is a language aware diff tool would be better equipped at showing you what has changed in a program than a pure text one.

Comment: It's not hard, it's virtually impossible, sometimes it works, sometimes it will hit hard. I remember a situation when method order change was a workaround of a Hibernate bug. And hence, a stupid text diff works much more reliable and easier to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this solution won't work in all the cases (for example when adding fields, I might need a 3 line context before, to locate where to insert, but I don't care about the context after (in case something else was already inserted).